# Could not find corresponding event log from 0x aggregator contract

Tags: events, 0x, logs

Looking at the event log from the 0x Protocol aggregator contract ("0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"), I could not find corresponding event to the following log topics0 "0xac75f773e3a92f1a02b12134d65e1f47f8a14eabe4eaf1e24624918e6a8b269f".

I browsed through the documentation here (https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/basics/events.html) but could not find the corresponding event. However, it looks similar to RfqOrderFilled event without the "pool" argument. Indeed, looking at the hex of the output of the event, the type seems to correspond well:

Unknown event:
[image]

RfqOrderFilled event (topics0: 0x829fa99d94dc4636925b38632e625736a614c154d55006b7ab6bea979c210c32):
[image]

Anyone would have any clue of what event it corresponds to ? I would like to verify the hash of the topics0 so I need the name of the event and the type of the arguments.

Thanks very much for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

The event is OtcOrderFilled.
It should something like the following:
Event OtcOrderFilled(bytes32 OrderHash, address maker,address taker, address makerToken, address TakerToken, uint128 makerAmount, uint128 takerAmount)

Hash of 'OtcOrderFilled(bytes32,address,address,address,address,uint128,uint128)' is '0xac75f773e3a92f1a02b12134d65e1f47f8a14eabe4eaf1e24624918e6a8b269f'